# Share one function in one service to the second service in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a module in AngularJS. I have two controllers (app.factory) who help to the module in validations etc.

I have one function of validation in controller 1 and i need it also in controller 2. 
How may i connect this function between these two controllers?

I don't copy this function to the two controllers of course.

Comment: You can try to define the function as a service and inject it into the two controller. Show some code so that we can help.

Comment: From what you've written, you don't understand the difference between angular service (`.factory`/`.service`) and controller (`.controller`). If you are using `.factory` it's not a controller, but a service